# NGINX - improve speed of requests to ads.txt and robots.txt

Tags: nginx

The structure of one of our sites has many subdomains, millions of them (this is for a good reason, of course). This means that Google crawler must access the /ads.txt and /robots.txt files for each subdomain, and I can see on our server hundreds of requests every second for these files.

In this case, what would be the most efficient way of serving these requests?

I currently use this:

```
    location = /robots.txt  {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        alias /home/sys/example.com/public/robots.txt;
    }
    location = /ads.txt  {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        alias /home/sys/example.com/public/ads.txt;
    }
```

My intention here is to point the robots and ads txt files to the same location on each request, although I don't know if that itself makes any difference. Also, turning off logging with "access_log off;" seemed like a good idea.

I believe it may be possible to return the txt file contents directly from nginx - would that be faster (less demanding on the nginx service)?

Comment: Using `root /home/sys/example.com/public;` would be more efficient than using `alias`;

Comment: Thanks. I've made this switch but haven't seen any improvements. When Google hits my server for these file requests, my server CPU climbs by about 40%! Really hoping to find some solution (aside from not using subdomains, as that's not really doable in this case).

Comment: Do these files differ between domains?

Comment: No they don't differ between all the subdomains.

Answer (score 1):

How are big these txt files? 
If they aren’t big you can serve them by putting the content directly in your configuration, ie:

```
location /robots.txt {
    return 200 'file content bla bla bla’;
    add_header Content-Type text/html; 
}
```

You can also add new line in content by using \n escape character

Comment: Pretty small. I've actually done this currently, it's not making any noticeable different though.

Comment: @NAMAssist ok, in this case I don't think that disk I/O is your bottleneck. How many worker (param worker_processes) are you using? And how many connections per worker (worker_connections)?
You can check that your worker are consistent with your CPUs. You can also try to increase the process priority (worker_priority) and to tune your Linux environment (like TCP params in sysctl).

These posts on nginx blog can be useful: https://www.nginx.com/blog/tuning-nginx/ https://www.nginx.com/blog/performance-tuning-tips-tricks/
Read also this example: https://gist.github.com/denji/8359866

Comment: worker_processes auto; worker_connections 12288; the server has 12 (shared) CPUs with 48gb ram. I can share my nginx config if it helps to find the bottleneck?